# Running the same brms model more than once gives widely different number of divergences. Why?

Tags: brms

I have been running brms models with in the zero-inflated poisson family. If I run the model and get some high r hat values (1.4) and many divergences. If I run the same model again, without making any changes, I can get a good fit, all rhats < 1.01, good numbers of ESS's, and a small number of divergences. Note that I don't specify a seed nymber.
What is happening? Does the first run influence the second run, even though the compilation is repeated?

I didn't try any changes.